# No windows frames on VNC screen

Tags: x11, gnome, vnc, upstart, headless

I am trying to configure good virtual desktop on my headless headless Ubuntu 14.04 server.

Unfortunately, I see the following picture when open remote screen:

[image]

I.e. windows have no frames and titles.

I run VNC with the following `/etc/init/Xvnc4.conf` (upstart script?):

```
description "VNC screen for Dims"

start on (local-filesystems and started dbus and stopped udevtrigger)
stop on runlevel [016]

expect fork

script

     /usr/bin/Xvnc4 :0 -geometry 1280x1024 -PasswordFile /root/.vnc/passwd &
     cd /root
     export HOME=/root
     export DISPLAY=:0
     export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
     export LANGUAGE=en_US:en
     ~/.vnc/xstartup
end script
```

I have the following content in `/root/.vnc/xstartup`

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &

#x-window-manager &
# mwm &
gnome-session &
```

`/etc/vnc/xstartup` is absent

`/root/.Xresources` is absent

What is wrong here?

Comment: Is your script `/root/.vnc/xstartup` executable?

Comment: @roaima yes, it apparently runs `terminal` etc

Answer (score 2):

Try running `gnome-session` like so:

```
if test -z "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" ; then
    eval `dbus-launch --sh-syntax –exit-with-session`
fi
gnome-session &
```

As pointed out in the comments, running `gnome-wm` instead of `gnome-session` may yield better results.

Comment: Doesn't using `exec` contradict `expect fork` setting in config?

Comment: Sorry, your proposition didn't help. The better results I get if write `gnome-wm &`

Comment: Good to know, updated the answer for those who might come searching through Google.