# Where are minimized windows in naked Xvnc4? How to restore minimized windows?

Tags: x11, desktop, vnc

I am running VNC server as described here: [No windows frames on VNC screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235659/no-windows-frames-on-vnc-screen)

I am running only few applications, so I have empty desktop and terminal in the beginning. If I run some application, like Eclipse, I am getting it's window normally. Unfortunately, when I minimize it, it goes somewhere down and no way to find it anymore.

Where are they? How to restore minimized windows in Xvnc4? May be I need to run some extra program for taskbar functionality?